# XSLT: Apply template to the result of another one

Tags: xslt

I want to transform following XML to JSON:

```
<Table>
    <Row>
        <Column name="Column 1">outter quotation text and &amp;qout;inner quotation text&amp;qout;</Column>
        <Column name="Column 2">

Some text with two 'new line' characters at the beginning (sometimes with &amp;qout;inner quotation text&amp;qout; also)</Column>
    </Row>
</Table>
```

To have valid json, I should remove all 'new line' characters (`&#xA;`) and replace `&amp;qout;` to `\"`.

Looks like this code helps to remove 'new lines':

```
<xsl:template name="escapeNewLine">
    <xsl:param name="pText" select="." />
        <xsl:if test="string-length($pText) > 0">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(concat($pText, '&#xA;'), '&#xA;')" />
        <xsl:if test="contains($pText, '&#xA;')">
            <xsl:text></xsl:text>
            <xsl:call-template name="escapeNewLine"><xsl:with-param name="pText" select="substring-after($pText, '&#xA;')" /></xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

and something similar to replace quotes:

```
 <xsl:template name="escapeQuote">
        <xsl:param name="pText" select="." />
        <xsl:if test="string-length($pText) > 0">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(concat($pText, '&amp;qout;'), '&amp;qout;')" />
            <xsl:if test="contains($pText, '&amp;qout;')">
                <xsl:text>\"</xsl:text>
                <xsl:call-template name="escapeQuote">
                    <xsl:with-param name="pText" select="substring-after($pText, '&amp;qout;')" />
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:if>
       </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
```

My stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="text" />
<xsl:template match="/">
"data":[
<xsl:for-each select="Table/Row">
    <xsl:if test="position() > 1">,</xsl:if>
    {
    <xsl:for-each select="Column">
        <xsl:if test="position() > 1">,</xsl:if>
        "<xsl:value-of select="@name" />":
        "
        <xsl:call-template name="escapeQuote" />
        <xsl:call-template name="escapeNewLine" />
        <!-- <xsl:value-of select="." /> -->
        "
    </xsl:for-each>
    }
</xsl:for-each>]
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My question is how to apply both templates to the same node? so instead of this:

```
{"data":[
    {"Column 1":"outter quotation text and \"inner quotation text\" outter quotation text and &amp;qout;inner quotation text&amp;qout;"},    
    {"Column 2":"Some text with two 'new line' characters at the beginning (maybe with \"inner quotation text\" also)

    Some text with two 'new line' characters at the beginning (maybe with &amp;qout;inner quotation text&amp;qout; also)"}}
]}
```

I could have this result:

```
{"data":
    [{"Column 1":"outter quotation text and \"inner quotation text\""},
     {"Column 2":"Some text with two 'new line' characters at the beginning (maybe with \"inner quotation text\" also)"}}
    ]}
```

Comment: You're using `&amp;qout;` in your input XML and XSLT. Was that intentional?  Should it perhaps be `&amp;quot;` or just `&quot;`?

Comment: Yes, it's ridiculous) but I have no influence on xml input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you need to do:

```
<xsl:call-template name="escapeQuote">
  <xsl:with-param name="pText">
    <xsl:call-template name="escapeNewLine" />
  </xsl:with-param>
</xsl:call-template>
```

It's also possible to have some code reuse here, and to convert the two types of newlines into `\r` and `\n` instead of just removing them:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="text" />
  <xsl:template match="/">
    "data":[
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Table/Row" />
    ]
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Row" name="RowData">
    {
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Column" />
    }
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Row[position() > 1]">
    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
    <xsl:call-template name="RowData" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Column" name="ColumnData">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('&quot;', @name, '&quot;:')" />

    <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
    <xsl:call-template name="escapeQuote">
      <xsl:with-param name="pText">
        <xsl:call-template name="escapeNewLine" />
      </xsl:with-param>
    </xsl:call-template>
    <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Column[position() > 1]">
    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
    <xsl:call-template name="ColumnData" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="escapeNewLine">
    <xsl:param name="pText" select="." />

    <xsl:call-template name="replace">
      <xsl:with-param name="pText">
        <xsl:call-template name="replace">
          <xsl:with-param name="pText" select="$pText" />
          <xsl:with-param name="from" select="'&#xA;'" />
          <xsl:with-param name="to" select="'\n'" />
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:with-param>
      <xsl:with-param name="from" select="'&#xD;'" />
      <xsl:with-param name="to" select="'\r'" />
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="escapeQuote">
    <xsl:param name="pText" select="." />

    <xsl:call-template name="replace">
      <xsl:with-param name="pText" select="$pText" />
      <xsl:with-param name="from" select="'&amp;qout;'" />
      <xsl:with-param name="to" select="'\&quot;'" />
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="replace">
    <xsl:param name="pText" />
    <xsl:param name="from" />
    <xsl:param name="to" />

    <xsl:if test="string-length($pText) > 0">
      <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(concat($pText, $from), $from)" />
      <xsl:if test="contains($pText, $from)">
        <xsl:value-of select="$to" />
        <xsl:call-template name="replace">
          <xsl:with-param name="pText" select="substring-after($pText, $from)" />
          <xsl:with-param name="from" select="$from" />
          <xsl:with-param name="to" select="$to" />
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```